# Django class based generic view redirect

Tags: python, django

Consider the following:

urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    ('^test/$', ClassView.as_view()),
)
```

views.py:

```
class ClassView(View):
    def get(self, request):
        return HttpResponse("test")
    def post(self, request):
        # do something
        return redirect(ClassView.get(request)) # What should I do to redirect to a class here without specifying the path?
```

I want to redirect to ClassView's get function (/test/), but when I try the above I get:

```
NoReverseMatch at /test/
```

So it obviously finds the URL but says that there's no match?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should just name your urlpattern and redirect to that, that would be the most Django-ey way to do it.

It's not documented (so not guaranteed to work in future Django versions) but the `redirect` shortcut method can take a view function, so you can *almost* do `redirect(ClassView.as_view())` ...I say almost because this doesn't actually work - every time you call `as_view()` you get a *new* view function returned, so `redirect` doesn't recognise that as the same view as in your urlconf.

So to do what you want, you'd have to update your urlconf like so:

```
from .views import test_view

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    ('^test/$', test_view),
)
```

And in your views.py

```
class ClassView(View):
    def get(self, request):
        return HttpResponse("test")

    def post(self, request):
        # do something
        return redirect(test_view)

test_view = ClassView.as_view()
```

But I still think you should do it the other way:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url('^test/$', ClassView.as_view(), name="test"),
)
```

.

```
class ClassView(View):
    def get(self, request):
        return HttpResponse("test")

    def post(self, request):
        # do something
        return redirect("test")
```

Comment: If there is nothing custom in the `post `method then a cleaner way to do this is to declare `ClassView` with a mixin like `django.views.generic.edit.FormMixin` then add the `success_url ` class member declaration, `success_url = reverse_lazy('test')`.  Then you can completely omit the declaration of `post`.

Comment: @nmgeek yes, nice point! ...although the OP did have that `# do something` comment in the `post` method that suggests maybe some custom stuff was happening

Answer (score 2):

May be you should set name to your urlpattern and redirect to that name?

Comment: That is one option but I'd prefer to just redirect to the class name if possible.

Comment: As alredy answered by @anentropic, it's possible to redirect to pre-instantiated view class.

But if you use it somewhere else in you project, you redirect can be broken because Django doesn't known which urlpattern is right.

Answer (score 1):

```
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    return HttpResponseRedirect(request.path)
```

This will redirect to the same URL as your `post()`, and then get handled by your `get()`.

Answer (score 0):

Try return `self.get()`. I didn't test. But as its a python code it should work. Use this if you only want to execute the statements. This will not return any HTTP 302 status I think.